# jQuery find and check box based on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that is generated by PHP and rendered to the page for jQuery to use. The object can contain multiple records / values. The object contains an ID number and an employeeID.

```
[

  {

  "intID": "202",

  "text": "Dav123"

 }


]
```

I have checkboxes that are on the page that I am trying to check based on the data in the object. Here is an example of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Dav123" intid="202" class="projectMember">
```

I am trying to loop through the object and check all of the boxes where the `intID` and `empID` match a checkbox on the page.

I tried doing something like this but it wouldnt check anything.

```
jQuery.each(preload_presenters, function(i, val) {
  var intID = val.intID,
      empID = val.text;

      $('.projectMember').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('intid') == intID && $(this).val() == empID) {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);  
            } 
      })
});
```

Any ideas of a cleaner / functional way to accomplish this?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/oo7w5gnd/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xvhLutbq/ ,
it seems you should check how you pass data from PHP. Check array on js side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `intid` is not a standard attribute for a checkbox and will render the page invalid, meaning you could get some odd UI/JS behaviour. If you can, change it to use a `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Dav123" data-intid="202" class="projectMember">
```

Then in your JS you can use filter to find that specific element by the attributes you've got:

```
jQuery.each(preload_presenters, function(i, val) {
    $('.projectMember').filter(function(){
        return this.value == val.text && $(this).data('intid') == val.intID;
    }).prop('checked', true);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/39csz0cy/)